# Why enzyme tests did not work in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am using Enzyme tests within Create-React-App. In `shallow` rendering it works fine, but `mount` rendering throws error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'favorites' of undefined

Test file looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Favorites from "../Landing/Favorites";

const mockStore = configureMockStore();
const store = mockStore({});

function setup() {
  const props = {
    favorites: 42
  };
  const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Favorites {...props} />
    </Provider>
  );
  return {
    props,
    wrapper
  };
}

describe("Favorites component", () => {
  const { wrapper } = setup();
  it("should render list of favorites cards", () => {
    expect(wrapper.prop("favorites")).toEqual(42);
  });
});
```

Why did it happen?

Comment: You have to do wrapper.props().favorites, no?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's throw the same error.

Comment: Could you provide us the output of "wrapper.debug()"?

Answer (score 0):

`.prop` works different in mount and shallow. You can check the docs.
http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/prop.html
http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/prop.html

When using `mount`, you can directly render Favorites component. 
`mount(<Favorites {...props} />)`

Comment: Thanks, but in this case throw another error:
`Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Favorites)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Favorites)".`